# Is There A Way To Create A Joint Intellij Project Spanning Multiple Gradle Projects As Modules

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

So it actually seems to mostly work, with both projects as sub-modules of the overall project. But the major annoyance is that when I debug in one of the modules, if code calls something in the other module it picks up the dependency from the Gradle cache instead of the other project/module's code and steps into a decompiled .class file from its cache instead of the actual source code.

I'd like to find a way so Intellij recognizes one module is using the other and uses the source code from the module itself which is of course checked out and available in the local filesystem.

Comment: How are you adding dependencies between your modules?

Comment: You mean in build.gradle? Yes but at the Maven artifact level, there is nothing telling IntelliJ that one depends on another unless it can infer that itself from build.gradle or from the fact that I added them as IntelliJ modules under the same IntelliJ project

Answer (score 2):

See [gradle documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) about setting up multiple projects as "sub-modules", though gradle lingo usually refers to them as sub-projects.

Basically, if you have some projects that are sub projects of a root project, you would setup the folder structure like this:

```
root
├───build.gradle
├───settings.gradle
│
├───subA
│    └───build.gradle
├───subB
│    └───build.gradle
└───subC
     └───build.gradle
```

In your root `settings.gradle`, you include your sub projects by adding:

```
include 'subA', 'subB', 'subC'
```

From this point on, you can refer to any project in your setup from any other project by its name: `project(':subB')`

so If you want to add `subC` as a compile time dependency of `subA`, in subA's build.gradle, you would have:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':subC')
}
```

Declared this way, the dependency is on the current files of subC instead of the last built/installed binaries from the repository. You could also have root project just a holder project with no code of its own.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can create such a root project solely to get Intellij to recognize the relationship. In source control we actually want to keep the projects separate. Thanks for the idea, I'll try it out.

Comment: super cool, I basically used your idea to create a parent project only for my local dev with the settings.gradle you described, also set a System property in my local ~/.gradle/gradle.properties of the form systemProp.mode=dev then in my projectA that depends on project B made the dependency conditional, on the project B if mode is dev, regular artifact style otherwise. Then imported into IntelliJ and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success using dependency substitution in a development mode kinda like this:

```
if (project.has("devMode")) {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
      substitute module("foo.group:bar") with project(":bar")
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully something like that may work for you, too.

EDIT: note that you'll also have to conditionally add the `:bar` project in settings.gradle as well

Comment: Thanks, let me play with that, give me some direction to try at least